# Delete/clear sqlite dB without restarting the app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an Sqlite do in my and I would like to give the user the option to be able to reload the dB. Therefore I want to programmatically clear the dB and execute whatever I have in OnCreate method to setup the tables

I used context.deleteDatabases(dbName) 
and initialized the object.

The problem is that it is not taking effect untill I restart the application. Is there a different way of doing it or a solution for this? Thank you

Comment: may be because you are not recreating the Activity.

Comment: OnCreate method will be called when the database is created for the first time. So, even u clear the database, the oncreate won't be called again. When u restart the application, ur Oncreate method will be called. So, it got reflected when u restarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reopen the database after the delete by using [`getWriteableDatabase()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()). This will cause a database to be created and your `onCreate` callback will be called again.

Comment: I do that already. After deleting the dB, I create another instance of the dB which calls OnCreate. I do getwriteable and I add some rows. Nothing appears untill I kill the app and start it again